# Error 404 on Apache server with codeigniter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

It's my first time i'm uploading codeigniter project to production and i'm getting error 404 from Apache server.

**error :** 
*Not Found
The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at roy.my-domain.com Port 80*

I've read every article for 2 days and didn't found a solution....

So here are my settings :

Checked for rewrite mod in Apache - got "Module rewrite already enabled"
My project is in **/var/www/roy/** so the url is **roy.my-domain.com/roy**

1. Apache2.conf

   ```
   <Directory /var/www/html/>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
   </Directory>
   AccessFileName .htaccess
   ```
2. .htaccess

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /roy/
   RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)\.html$ index.php/page/$1 [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|asset|robots\.txt)
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
   </IfModule>
   ```
3. config.php

   ```
   $config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/roy/';
   $config['index_page'] = '';
   ```
4. autoload.php (i'm using Twig)

   ```
   $autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session','twig');
   ```

   - I added permissions to both logs and cache dir
5. The controllers structure

   ```
   name Login.php - 
   class Login extends CI_Controller
   ```

Comment: Did you have the same path structure on your development server? Just to clarify, is `roy.my-domain.com/roy` the publicly accessible URL?

Comment: w3dk - Yes - i did have the same path - the project is working well on development

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a `site` folder inside your `html` one. Then, put your `roy` site there. Then, I would do it this way:

1 - apache2/sites-enabled/roy.my-domain.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost roy.my-domain.com:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site
    ServerName roy.my-domain.com
    <Directory /var/www/html/site>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

2 - .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

3 - If it's not development, it's never a good practice to use the `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` superglobal. Can be changed from the client side. Just use the right url.

After you're done all that, restart apache. In Ubuntu is: `$ sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: I'm curious how this actually solves the OP's problem? What was the problem with the OP's config, considering the development server appeared to work OK with the same path structure? At #2, where are you putting the `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your `.htaccess` file is in the `/roy` subdirectory?

Since you are making use of *path information* (ie. `/index.php/<path-info>` on the URL to route the request, it's possible that `AcceptPathInfo` is disabled on the server. If it's disabled then such a request would result in a 404.

So, try enabling this at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
AcceptPathInfo On
```

Comment: w3dk -i've tried it - still - error 404, another thing that i notice now - images are not displayed - their path is ok - <img src="<?php echo $this->config->item('base_url'); ?>public/assets/img/logo.png" alt="">